# Python ElementTree if elif else statement different child elements and values

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

For extracting data out of a HTML-file (CAMT-format), I have the following code:

```py
def create_entry(filename):

   root = parse_getroot(filename)[0]
   ns = create_namespace(filename)
   
   for child in root:
      for layer in child.findall(ns + 'Stmt'):
         for childlayer in layer.findall(ns + 'Ntry'):
            for ntrydtls in childlayer.findall(ns + 'NtryDtls'):
                for txdtls in ntrydtls.findall(ns + 'TxDtls'):
                    for rltdpties in txdtls.findall(ns + 'RltdPties'):
                            for dbtr in rltdpties.findall(ns + 'Dbtr'):
                                name.append(dbtr.find(ns + 'Nm').text)
                            for cdtr in rltdpties.findall (ns + 'Cdtr'):
                                name.append(cdtr.find(ns + 'Nm').text)
```

Now, I need the code that if there is no 'Nm' for the subset of 'Dbtr' or 'Cdtr', the code give it the value 'Not available'. I already tried this with the 'if dbtr (or cdtr) is not None', but then it creates double values. I have tried this on the other way like below, but I still get missing or double values. For me, this is the best way possible, but still is not working:

```py
def create_entry(filename):

   root = parse_getroot(filename)[0]
   ns = create_namespace(filename)
   
   for child in root:
      for layer in child.findall(ns + 'Stmt'):
         for childlayer in layer.findall(ns + 'Ntry'):
            for ntrydtls in childlayer.findall(ns + 'NtryDtls'):
                for txdtls in ntrydtls.findall(ns + 'TxDtls'):
                    for rltdpties in txdtls.findall(ns + 'RltdPties'):
                        
                        dbtr_list = rltdpties.findall(ns + 'Dbtr')
                        cdtr_list = rltdpties.findall(ns + 'Cdtr')
                        
                        if len(dbtr_list) == 0 and len(cdtr_list) == 0:
                            name.append('Not available')
                        else:
                            for dbtr in rltdpties.findall(ns + 'Dbtr'):
                                name.append(dbtr.find(ns + 'Nm').text)
                            for cdtr in rltdpties.findall (ns + 'Cdtr'):
                                name.append(cdtr.find(ns + 'Nm').text)
```

Again: the idea is that if there is no name for a 'Dbtr' of 'Cdtr', the script gives the data-point the string 'Not available'. Someone knows how to do this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including a a representative XML document.